# Array of binomial coefficients

Tags: java, arrays, pascals-triangle, binomial-coefficients

So, I have implemented the binomial coefficient

```java
public static int binomial(int n, int k) {
    if (k == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (k > n - k)
        return binomial(n, n - k);
    else
        return binomial(n - 1, k - 1) * n / k;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Insert n: ");
    int n = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Insert k: ");
    int k = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Result: " + binomial(n, k));
}
```

And it works, but where I'm stuck is just that I need to add the **coefficient array** for two given numbers. So If `n` is `5` and `k` is `3`. The coefficient array will display: `1 5 10 10`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is put your expression in a loop and hold `n` constant.

```java
for (int k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
    System.out.print(binomial(n, k) + " ");
}
```

You can store these values in an array if you like. There is no need to make your method any more complicated.

If want to put it in an array, here is one easy way to do it.

```java
int coefs[] = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, n).map(k -> binomial(n, k)).toArray();
```

```
coefs[] = [1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't call recursive code in a for loop. That adds a stupid amount of redundancy.

Pass the array as a parameter to the recursive function from main. Arrays are passed by reference in java.

```java
public static int binomial(int n, int k, int[] coefficient) {
    int ret;
    if (k == 0) {
        ret = 1;
    } else if (k > n - k) {
        ret = binomial(n, n - k, coefficient);
    } else {
        ret = binomial(n - 1, k - 1, coefficient) * n / k;
    }
    coefficient[k] = ret;
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create two *iterative* methods: one returns a 2d array containing *Pascal's triangle*, and the second returns the *base* of that triangle. It is more useful for clarity.

Output:

```
Insert n:
6
Pascal's triangle:
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 3, 6, 10]
[1, 4, 10]
[1, 5]
[1]
Binomial coefficients:
[1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
```

Code:

```java
public static int[][] binomialTriangle(int n) {
    // an array of 'n' rows
    int[][] arr = new int[n][];
    // iterate over the rows of the array
    IntStream.range(0, n).forEach(i -> {
        // a row of 'n-i' elements
        arr[i] = new int[n - i];
        // iterate over the columns of the array
        IntStream.range(0, n - i).forEach(j -> {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0)
                // first row and column
                // are filled with ones
                arr[i][j] = 1;
            else
                // all other elements are the sum of the
                // previous element in the row and column
                arr[i][j] = arr[i][j - 1] + arr[i - 1][j];
        });
    });
    return arr;
}
```

```java
public static int[] binomialCoefficient(int[][] triangle) {
    return Arrays.stream(triangle)
            // the last element in the row
            .mapToInt(row -> row[row.length - 1])
            .toArray();
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Insert n:");
    int n = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Pascal's triangle:");
    int[][] arr = binomialTriangle(n);
    Arrays.stream(arr).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);

    int[] base = binomialCoefficient(arr);
    System.out.println("Binomial coefficients:");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(base));
}
```

---

<sup>See also: [Convert negative index to positive index in an array (Trinomial Triangle)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66199688/14940971)</sup>