# Convert negative index to positive index in an array (Trinomial Triangle)

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find trinomial coefficients and I want to avoid using negative index in my array. There will be instances whereby i or j will become negative and will return array out of bounds error. Is there anyway I can mirror the array contained in the negative indexes to a positive index?

Here’s the recursive formula: [Recursion Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial_triangle#Recursion_formula)

I recognize that `T(0, -1) = T(0, 1)` but how do I implement it?

example:

```
row 0: T(0, 0) = 1 , T(0, 1) = 0 ...

row 1: T(1, 0) = T(0, -1) + T(0, 0) + T(0, 1) , T(2, 0) ...
```

The trinomial coefficient `T(n,k)` is the coefficient of `x^(n+k)` in the expansion of `(1+x+x^2)^n`.

Trinomial triangle (middle index is `0`, negative on the left of `0`, positive on the right of `0`):

[image]

Note: The code below iterates through the array from middle index `0` to the right.

```java
public class ClassNameHere {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int k = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        long[][] DP = new long[n + 1][k + 1];
        DP[0][0] = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= Math.min(i, k); j++) {
                if (i == j || ((j == 0) && i < 2)) DP[i][j] = 1;
                else if (j < -i) {
                    DP[i][j] = 0;
                } else DP[i][j] = DP[i - 1][j];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(DP[n][k]);
    }
}
```

Now I am able to get the terms from `T(0, 0)` to `T(1, 0)` with my code but unable to continue past `T(2, 0)` onwards by adding `T(1,0) + T(1, 1) + T(1, 2)`. When I tried to implement `DP[i][j] = DP[i - 1][j - 1] + DP[i - 1][j] + DP[i - 1][j + 1]`, it returns `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` again.. I think that something is wrong with the implementation of the above statement `^`. Any suggestions on how to go on with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause.

It can be done by initializing the correct length in the 2D array.

```
long[][] tri = new long[n + 1][k + n + 1];
```

and using Math.abs() to handle instances where j index will flow to negative indices.

```
tri[i][j] = tri[i - 1][Math.abs(j - 1)] + tri[i - 1][j] + tri[i - 1][j + 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can populate such an array as follows: first create a new empty array with height `n` and width `2n+1`, filled with zeros, and set the first entry at the upper midpoint to `1`, then iterate over the rows and columns and set the other entries, each equal to the sum of the three entries above it:

```java
T[i][j] = T[i-1][j-1] + T[i-1][j] + T[i-1][j+1];
```

Code:

```java
int n = 7;
// new array filled with zeros
int[][] arr = new int[n][2 * n + 1];
// first entry
arr[0][n] = 1;
// iterate over the rows of the array
// starting from the second
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // iterate over the columns of the array
    // from the second to the penultimate
    for (int j = 1; j < arr[i].length - 1; j++) {
        // each entry is the sum of the three entries above it
        arr[i][j] = arr[i - 1][j - 1] + arr[i - 1][j] + arr[i - 1][j + 1];
    }
}
```

```java
// output
for (int[] row : arr) {
    for (int cell : row)
        if (cell > 0)
            System.out.printf("%3d ", cell);
        else
            System.out.print("    ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
                              1                             
                          1   1   1                         
                      1   2   3   2   1                     
                  1   3   6   7   6   3   1                 
              1   4  10  16  19  16  10   4   1             
          1   5  15  30  45  51  45  30  15   5   1         
      1   6  21  50  90 126 141 126  90  50  21   6   1
```

---

<sup>See also: [Finding trinomial coefficients using dynamic programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66200610/14940971)</sup>